Isomorphism of real quaternion algebra with the Hamiltonian quaternion.
For a given quaternion algebra $A=\left(\frac{a,b}{\mathbb{R}}\right)$ where $a,b<0$, we know that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{H}$. Can I check if the following is the appropriate isomorphism mapping.
Let $\{1,i,j,ij\}$ and $\{1,i',j',i'j'\}$ be standard $\mathbb{R}$-basis of $A$ and $\mathbb{H}$. Then mapping $$i \mapsto i'$$ $$j \mapsto j'$$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-algebra isomorphism.
Reason for asking is that this is a mapping that one of my senior gave me but I'm not entirely sure why this is true. Any hints will be helpful! Thanks!
EDIT: I'm thinking the reason is because we're working over $\mathbb{R}$, thus if $i^2 = a$, we can think of $i = \sqrt{a}$ which is a complex number. Likewise for $j = \sqrt{b}$. Thus $i= \sqrt{a} = -ai'$ and $j = \sqrt{b} = -bj' $ where $ (j')^2=(i')^2 = -1$, the usual imaginary number. In this case $-a$ is just a real number that can be 'absorbed'. Therefore, $$ A= \mathbb{R} + \mathbb{R}i +\mathbb{R}j + \mathbb{R}ij$$ can be written as $$ A = \mathbb{R} + \mathbb{R}i' + \mathbb{R}j' + \mathbb{R}i'j'.$$ Thus the mapping given above is an isomorphism. Would like to know if this is a correct way of thinking about this.

No, this is not true at all. If what you mean by your notation is that $i, j \in \mathbb H$ and $i', j' \in A$ then
$$
  i^2 = j^2 = -1\quad\text{but}\quad (i')^2 = a,\; (j')^2 = b
$$
so there is no way your mapping can give an isomorphism as it is not even a (unital) algebra homomorphism. Even if we don't want our algebras to be unital, assume such an isomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb H \to A$ exists;
then
$$
  a = (i')^2 = \varphi(i)^2 = \varphi(i^2) = \varphi(j^2) = \varphi(j)^2 = (j')^2 = b,
$$
so such an isomorphism cannot exist unless $a = b$. But even if this were the case
$$
  a = \varphi(i^2) = \varphi(k^2) = \varphi(ijij) = -\varphi(i^2j^2) = -(i')^2(j')^2 = -a^2
$$
so $a = b = -1$.

The correct way to get an isomorphism is the "obvious" way
$$
  i \mapsto i'/\sqrt{-a},\quad j \mapsto j'/\sqrt{-b}.
$$

Hi thank you so much! This makes much more sense to me now!
